# Security testing in soap ui or Burp suite?

Tags: soapui, burp

we are testing a secuirty testing for web application. I am new to testing using BURP Suite. I do have extensive knowledge in Soap UI for webservice testing but have NOT used for security testing. Does anybody know the comparison of the tools or which is best to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

soapui is ws-security compliant . I have used same for adding usernametoken which was consumed by secured soap service. It have authentications support based on plaintext, password digest/signature and encryption.